# Getting data from an SVG file using PHP

Tags: php, svg

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate question or not but I'll ask it anyway.

How do I take image data from an SVG file and pass it into PHP, then output the info with HTML?  I know it can be done in Javascript, but that's not how this particular project needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `file_get_contents` to read svg file data in php.

```
$templateString= array(
    'front' => file_get_contents($svgUrl, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)
);

echo $templateString;
```

Now complete svg data is in `$templateString` variable.

Comment: you need to convert the array to string before echo... than it work for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and got my SVG XML content from URL.

```
$svg_file = file_get_contents($url);

echo $svg_file;
```